# Unwanted Boostrap gutter spacing/margin/padding between rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Problem: 
[image]

Do you see the gutter spacing between them? I'd like to get rid of that and add custom ones to match the margin at the bottom.

Here's the page's code:

```
#posts
    .row
        - @posts.each do |post|
            .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3
                .post
                    .post_content
                        .title
                            %h2
                                = link_to truncate((post.title), length: 25), post
                        %p
                            $
                            = post.price
                        .post_image
                            = link_to image_tag(post.image.url), post
                        .data.clearfix
                            %p.username
                                Listing by
                                = post.user.name
                            %p.buttons
                                %span
                                    %i.fa.fa-comments-o
                                    = post.inquiries.count
                                %span
                                    %i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up
                                    = post.get_likes.size
```

And of course, the CSS:

```
#posts {
    .post {
        margin: .5rem;
        border: 1px solid #9B9B9B;
        &:hover {
            border: 1px solid white;
        };
        .post_image {
            height: 20rem;
            overflow: hidden;
            img {
                width: 100%;
                border-radius: .3rem .3rem 0 0;
            }
        }
        .post_content {
            margin: 1rem;
            h2 {
                margin: 0;
                font-weight: 100;
                padding: 1rem;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    /*color: #333233;*/
                    &:hover {
                        color: #6E58E0;
                    }
                }
            }
            .data {
                /*padding: .75rem 5%;*/
                color: #969696;
                .username, .buttons {
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 1rem;
                }
                .username {
                    float: left;
                }
                .buttons {
                    float: right;
                    span {
                        margin-left: .5rem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, you should show me how to style it so that the individual posts are squares with even margin between them.

Comment: Create a demo of your code please.

Comment: Are you working with the Sass/Less version of Bootstrap, or the compiled CSS version?

Comment: Inspect the horizontal padding and margins of your columns in a browser. Adjust them in real time and observe what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this (the other answer had the same idea but you don't need the commas since you're using HAML):

```
.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3 {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

The reason is that Boostrap's row comes preloaded with paddings (not margins) of 35px and 15px. Therefore you need to reset it or set your own.

Answer (score 0):

In the Sass version of Bootstrap, find the _variables.scss file. Search for "$grid-gutter-width". You can adjust this value to whatever you want to affect the gutter width.

The default gutter width is this:

```
   $grid-gutter-width:         30px !default;
```

Change that to something smaller to see if that works.

If you're working in the already compiled version of Bootstrap, you'll have to adjust this crazy set of code:

```
.col-lg-1,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9,.col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-sm-1,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9,.col-xs-1,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-11,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-3,.col-xs-4,.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7,.col-xs-8,.col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px
}
```

Adjust the padding-left and padding-right here, or override them in your own css.

Comment: I have no idea where to find that :/ There's no _variables file...I'm using Rails btw

Comment: @HenryLee I downloaded the Sass version of Bootstrap. I found that file here: bootstrap-sass-3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't override default css, like in most answers.
To keep the default bootstrap css you could use this:

```
<div class="customdiv">
    <div class="col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3">
         content here
     </div>
</div>
```

You can than add the styling to customdiv.

```
 .customdiv{
   boder:2px red;//or something
 }
```

When you override the bootstrap css you dont have the padding anymore at spots where you do want the padding.